# Best way to save "event" data on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an app running on AWS and I need to save every "event" in a file.
An "event" happens, for instance, when a user logs in to the app. When that happens I need to save this information on a file (presumably I would need to save a time stamp and the session id)

I expect to have a lot of events (of the order of a million per month) and I was wondering what would be the best way to do this.

I thought of writing on S3, but I think I can't append to existing files.

Another option would be to redirect the "event" to the standard output, but would not be the smartest solution.

Any ideas? Also, this needs to be done in python.

Comment: a million per year? per day? per second?

Comment: per month. I just edited the question

Answer (score 2):

There are bunch of options, and your choice would depend on following factors:

- Scale of these events.
- Cost you are willing to bear.
- How you intend on consuming them.

Options:

- Log every event into a [Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/) stream, which in turn can dump your data into S3 or Redshift, as per your configuration.
- Setup an [Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) cluster. Log all events in a file on disk, and use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to asynchronously push these into the cluster.
- Create a [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) table and log one event per row.

Answer (score 0):

Using CloudWatch Logs you can [export the logs to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html). You can use the [CloudWatch Logs agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) to send your application log file to CloudWatch.